# how to pass oracle variable in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, oracle11g

How to pass a oracle variable into javascript:

I want to write function like this:

here l_cnt_result is oracle variable.

```
function descCheck(select) { 
  var opt_K_count = "|| l_cnt_result || ";
  var opt = select.options[select.options.selectedIndex];
  alert("opt.value = " + opt.value ); 
  alert("opt_K_count = " + opt_K_count); 

  if (opt_K_cnt == 9 ) { 
    alert("Count will be incremented to multiple of 10");
  }
};
```

alert(opt.value} part works.. but for the opt_K_count doesnt...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this within a webpage?  If so you'd need to have something server side that  can interpret an ajax call and do the interaction with your database, and then return the count variable back to your javascript via a callback function.